# struct storage size error not reported by GCC with optimization turned on

Tags: c, gcc, struct, compiler-optimization

In a file struct_test.c I write:

```
static struct x x;
```

and I compile with GCC (4.8.2, Ubuntu)

```
gcc -c -O0 struct_test.c
```

I get the understandable error:

```
error: storage size of 'x' isn't known
```

Then I recompile, this time with optimization turned on

```
gcc -c -O struct_test.c
```

and the file is compiled without error.

I can kind of understand why turning on optimization removed the error but can someone help me to get the actual compiler option which is instructing gcc to ignore the undefined tag 'x'?

Comment: This should be *trivial* to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (stress the *complete*). Do so.

Comment: Do you use `x` anywhere? Could the optimizer be removing an unused declaration, and therefore it doesn't complain that it doesn't know the size?

Comment: @TripeHound Ofcourse I am not using 'x' anywhere. What I am trying to understand is which compiler options instructs the optimizer to ignore the unused declaration.

Comment: @TripeHound if it does that at compile time, its whacked.  If `struct x` isn't a known type upon arrival to that line (we still don't know if that is the case since there is no mcve), that line shouldn't compile *regardless*,

Comment: @ WhozCarig, Sorry but I think the questions fulfills MCVE criteria, its a one-line simplified program which compiles differently with/without optimizations.

Comment: The option you look for is `-fdce` (dead code elimination) which is a part of `-O`.

Comment: @WhozCraig The question is quite complete (MVCE) and the problem is reproducible. I am struggling to understand what more info you ask for.

Comment: My point was: if there _is_ a specific option, you should be looking for one that eliminates unused variables rather than one to "ignore the undefined tag 'x'".  As @Blue Moons response indicates.

Comment: @BlueMoon "In a file struct_test.c I write:" - is that the *only* thing written in that file? The first question (actually posted as an answer, then deleted) out of the gate by ike, was "How, and more importantly, where is struct x defined...". Posting four lines of code (a main.c) would have squelched that entirely and directed the reader straight to the meat of the question. And it would have taken less typing to do it than the first comment left by the OP. *That's* why I asked.

Comment: @fsheikh do yo also get a tentative declaration warning when this compiles in *either* mode (opt or not) ? clang emits one, does gcc? And fwiw, with or without opt, clang pukes on this, so whatever gcc is doing, its special

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thanks for following up. If I add -Wall in addition to -O (the compiler command line), then I do get a unused variable warning. But without -Wall it simply compiles without any diagnostic message. Hence the mystery...

Comment: @fsheikh How odd. You say you get an unused var warning but nothing about a tentative declaration warning/error? There must be something else that gcc has to exhibit that additional pedantic level. It is certainly possible gcc has no such warning/error, and doesn't bother with the error at link time since the var is tripped with opti anyway (what you're *likely* seeing now). Uptick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it appears at file scope, this code:

```
static struct x x;
```

declares `x` as an object of type `struct x` and having internal linkage.  The type `struct x` need not have previously been declared:

> If a type specifier of the form `struct-or-union identifier` occurs other than [in a struct type declaration], and no other declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the tag of that type.

(C99 6.7.2.3/8)

A structure or union type that is incomplete when first encountered in a translation unit can nevertheless be completed later in that translation unit:

> A structure or union type of unknown content [...] is an incomplete type. It is completed, for all declarations of that type, by declaring the same structure or union tag with its defining content later in the same scope.

(C99 6.2.5/22)

C discriminates between "declarations" generally, which specify the type of an object, and "definitions", which both specify the type and cause storage to be reserved.  In a given translation unit, declarations that are not definitions may have incomplete type that is *never* completed within that unit.

Section 6.9.2 of C99 specifies which file-scope object declarations are definitions:

- a declaration with file scope and an initializer is a definition (specifically, an "external definition", even though the object it defines may have internal linkage)
- declaration with file scope and no initializer, and having static storage class or no storage class specifier is a "tentative definition".  If the translation unit contains no external definition of the same object, then behavior is as if there were an external definition having initializer `0`.

This section also specifies that "If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a tentative definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an incomplete type."  That applies here, but since a type that is incomplete at one point in the translation unit can be completed by a later declaration, it does not inherently invalidate the line of code in question.  However, it *does* invalidate a translation unit containing only that line.

### So what's up with GCC?

Inasmuch as the code given, taken as a complete translation unit, violates a "shall not" language constraint, it yields undefined behavior.  GCC is not obligated to reject the code or produce any kind of diagnostic, though it is permitted to do either or both.  As it turns out, regardless of optimization level, `gcc` does issue a warning about the code if the `-Wall` or `-pedantic` flag is turned on.  Any way around, `gcc` explicitly disclaims being a tool for validating standard compliance of your code.

This particular violation is relatively benign, however.  Because the object is never referenced, `gcc` can pretend it was never even declared without risking wrong or unintended behavior.

The `-fdce` (dead code elimintation) option seems to be one that affects this particular behavior.  Oddly, although `-fdce` is enough to suppress the error at optimization level `O0`, `-fno-dce` does not bring it back at higher optimization levels.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: Since this is a 'shall not' requirement in the spec, a program that violates it causes undefined behavior -- which means a conforming compiler is not *required* to diagnose anything, and can do anything (including simply ignoring it as unused, as gcc does here).

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisDodd.  I have revised the last part of my comments in light of your observation.